# How to get pygame to work in python3 on my Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame, pycharm

I have been trying to figure this out for days now. I have installed Homebrew, pip3, and probably a bunch of other things that I should not have installed, and I still cannot get Idle or PyCharm to recognize that I do in fact have pygame.

I have seen many different tutorials and questions on here, but most are from 2013 or older and none of them worked.

All I want to do is get pygame installed as a module that works in python3.

I am using a MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.15.4

Any help its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) website:

> You can use this command: `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`.
>
> Then to test, use `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure you enter the exact command, don't enter `pip install -U pygame --user`, because idle won't recognize it.